# React linter suggesting to wrap constant array with useMemo inside useEffect react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React linter is giving a warning:

> The 'someUnchangingArray' array makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 42) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'someUnchangingArray' in its own useMemo() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Why? `someUnchangingArray` is a constant and wont change, why is React linter suggesting that it will trigger the `useEffect` on every render?

```
export default function Component(
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  const someUnchangingArray = ["1", ""];
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized) {
      // do some iniitializing
      console.log(someUnchangingArray, initialized);
      setInitialized(true);
    }
  }, [someUnchangingArray, initialized]);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is a function that is called on every render.
It means that on every render `someUnchangingArray`  will point to a newly created reference of an array.
`useEffect` will receive a new reference and will decide that it's time to be called.

```js
function render() {
  const someUnchangingArray = ["1", ""];
  return someUnchangingArray
}

console.log(render() === render()); // false
```

Here is an illustration:

```js
function Component() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const supposedlySomeUnchangingArray = ["1", ""];
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.count('USE EFFECT HAS BEEN CALLED');
  }, [supposedlySomeUnchangingArray]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {counter}
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>do something to rerender</button>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root">
</div>
```

Check the console and you will see that useEffect is called on each rerender.

Answer (score 1):

v-dom rerender basically means it will rerun all your component(function)

hence you will create new array reference for every render

simply move the constant outside

```
const someUnchangingArray = ["1", ""];

export default function Component(
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized) {
      // do some iniitializing
      console.log(someUnchangingArray, initialized);
      setInitialized(true);
    }
  }, [someUnchangingArray, initialized]);
...
```

or for whatever reason it need to be inside(rely on your state), then you need the useMemo hook